# How to do scrollable TabBar with multiple items in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I'm working on an app that needs many TabBar Items  morethan 5 so I'm wondering how to make my own TabBar that slides from left to right, so one can easily access all the buttons on the tabbar without pressing "More."

Comment: You can use `UIScrollView` and `UIButton`.

Comment: Use a TabbarController that you might be doing add all viewcontrollers etc, the trick is create a Custom UIView with a scrollview, and make a tabbar look like design add it on window and on click call `[tabbarcontroller setSelectedIndex:btn.tag];`

Comment: already i have done with 4 buttons in tab bar now i am working on add on features  in that i have to add 2 more buttons, so i dont want touch existing code, is there any other chance to add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use UICollectionView with horizontal scrolling OR use UIScrollView with Horizontal scrolling with custom Buttons.

OR add the tab bar into scrollview then give width to tabbar depends on the addition of tabitems. And Then set the contentSize of scrollview depends on tabbar width.